# Will Multiple Routers (Using Split-DHCPs for IP grouping) for Smart Home separation cause problems?

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking, dhcp-server, iot

I'm reconfiguring my home Wi-Fi & I'm trying to find the best way to deal with my Smart Home devices.

I have **≈70 Smart Home devices**, from a Google Home Mini in each room, Smart thermostat, smart plugs, smart lights, RoboVac, 5 smart TVs, but each with a Chromecast with Google TV on it, smart water leak sensor, smart water softener sensor, smart smoke/CO2 sensor, 2 HDHomerun Tuners, Broadlink RF Remote, 3 Harmony Hubs, etc.

I also run a server that has my home's Bluray player as well as media server, 3 NAS servers, plus the 5 laptops regularly used, 4 tablets, 8 phones, kids desktop AIO, an XBox One, PS4, 2 Nintendo Switches, & Other devices that are regularly used by regular guests.

As you can see, my current setup is quite crowded.

So I'm planning on setting up a **split DHCP** to keep all the smart home traffic IPs grouped, & together on a separate router, from congesting my new network WiFi channels.

So my Router connects to another, unsecured router before going out into the wilds of the internet. I don't want to put my router for the smart home stuff beside my main router because access to the media server, Bluray, Tuner, etc needs to be within the same subnet, plus dealing with a Double NAT is enough, I don't want a Triple NAT. I know I loose some security, but I'm alright with that.

So my 2nd router, my old one, is acting as a DHCP server serving **192.168.9.10-192.168.9.99** serving a 2.4GHz network on the slightly crowded **Ch1**, & an auto-managed 5GHz channel under an SSID we'll call **"SmartHomeX"** & **"SmartHomeX-5G"**. While my main router is serving everything else with a DHCP server serving **192.168.9.150-192.168.9.254** on the clear **ch11** for 2.4GHz, & 2 auto negotiated 5GHz channels under an SSID we'll call **"MainHomeB"**.

The **MainHome** router is **192.168.9.1** Static

The **SmartHome** router is **192.168.9.6** Static

Both are on the **255.255.255.0 Subnet**

The Routers are connected together from LAN-to-LAN, not by either'S WAN port.

My NAS, Media Server/Bluray, & the like use Static IPs in the **192.168.9.101-192.168.9.110** range & are connected via wire.

I've left some room between sets in case I find I need more room in one later on & in case I find the need to use Static Addresses in any of the categories (I know some of my smart home devices had issues without static addresses, if I run into those problems after the new setup I'll be prepared)

This setup is different from any I've done before & most of my Networking experience, my A+ & CCNA days, are from the the days before WiFi-N was a thing.

***Is there anything I should change?***

***Any problems I'm overlooking?***

---

**Clarification**

My goal for the Split-DHCP is to keep the SmartHome devices in an organized IP range. I originally setup the 2nd router as a dumb bridge with a separate SSID & had the main router handle all the DHCP. I'm not worried about DHCP traffic, rather I have an issue with some of the SmartHome devices, like Google Homes & Amazon FireSticks in particular, constantly having small traffic, multiple/minute, over the WiFi, essentially taking a seat on the "train" to hold a letter. I'd rather have a separate train to handle the mail, that may have some actual traffic, like when playing music on the Google Homes, but is mostly just the mail car.

I have had some issues with my previous setup that I initially thought was a bad router, because sometimes devices, laptops, tablets, smart TVs, say they have no internet. A restart of the device, or even a WiFi off/on usually fixes it, but the longer the router goes without a reset the more frequent the problems. I replaced the router & the problem persisted. There's always the possibility that the problem stems from the host Router & the Double NAT, but if so there's not much I can do to fix it. I hope to isolate the problem under the Split-DHCP setup to help me resolve it if possible, but my question is about any possible problems with the setup I am implementing.

---

I acknowledge the risk of the devices on **SmartHome** getting a DHCP address from the **MainHome** router or vice versa, but that should not, from my understanding, have any negative effects on the network, only on my organization charts, which I can live with.

Comment: Did you actually observe significant amounts of DHCP traffic? I'd expect barely any, even for ~100 devices. Permanently connected devices will acquire IP once every 24h (assuming 24h leases) and mobile ones will do so when entering WiFi range. I'm not sure about the smart home stuff but I'd guess most of them is permanently connected too.

Comment: It's not a lot of DHCP traffic, but each Google Home pings multiple times per minute, Every Firestick does multiple requests to the router every second & consume data (≈100MB/day) when not even being used. I removed those entirely because of this. My goal is to have the wifi "lanes" being used by the SmartHome devices separate. The problem I've had with multiple routers is devices loosing internet access, & having to be restarted if the router hasn't been restarted in the last day or 2. I thought it was a bad router, but a replacement, different brand, had the same problem.

Comment: The Split-DHCP is not to solve the problem, but if the problem happens again hopefully it will help me identify it

Answer (score 1):

> So I'm planning on setting up a split DHCP to keep all the smart home traffic from congesting my new network WiFi channels.

Those things have little to do with each other.

There is no 1-to-1 relationship between DHCP servers and Wi-Fi channels. A single IP subnet, with a single DHCP server, can be accessed through as many Wi-Fi APs as you like, each on its own band and frequency. (You also get automatic roaming between APs if their SSIDs are identical.)

(For a bit more pedantry, a DHCP server doesn't exactly *create* the new network – a router by itself does that; DHCP is more just "support" infrastructure. The DHCP service does not forward any of the actual traffic, only directs clients at the actual gateway.)

If your devices mostly work with regular 'unicast' traffic – packets from host A addressed specifically to host B – then separating them into different IP subnets won't change much in terms of performance. Separating them onto different Wi-Fi access points (on different channels) would have more of an impact, but it has nothing to do with IP or DHCP; you could easily have five access points on 5 different channels providing access to the same router, same subnet, etc.

Even more so, it sounds like your plan is to use the same subnet number for both DHCP servers. That is *not* going to help with congestion; it might only make other things worse. If the two are actually on separate subnets physically, then trying to reuse the same subnet number (192.168.9./24) for both will only prevent connectivity *between* the two subnets – and if both DHCP servers are on the same subnet, then having two will not help with dividing traffic.

Only if some devices spam a lot of 'broadcast' or 'multicast' packets, then the rest of the network *would* benefit of those devices being isolated to their own IP subnet as well. In this case, it may be useful to enable options like "IGMP snooping" or "Multicast enhancement" in your Wi-Fi access points.

(A packet capture tool like Wireshark would show whether it's receiving a large amount of broadcast packets, e.g. IoT "discovery" protocols.)

> My initial setup had the SmartHome router setup as a dumb bridge. Essentially keeping the SmartHome devices on a separate SSID. THAT is what is supposed to be reducing congestion of the WiFi "lanes" the Split-DHCP is just so the SmartHome devices stay in an IP range together

That sounds okay, but it's only going to work if the SmartHome router is no longer a bridge, but a full router (as otherwise all devices would still see both DHCP servers across bridges).

But, if it's no longer a bridge, then the two routers **must not** use the same IP network numbering. That is, it's *not enough* for only the DHCP lease ranges to be different – in your example, the two routers would still be operating in identical 192.168.9.0/24 networks overall.

One of the routers must have its "LAN interface" configuration changed, e.g. to use 192.168.8.0/24 or something like that.

> It's no longer a bridge, or rather once I implement it it will not be, but I NEED them to be on the same Subnet. Google Home Mini 1 on 192.168.9.56 needs to be able to see MediaServer on 192.168.9.106 to play the music stored there without sending it out & back onto the network, likewise MediaServer on 106 needs to see HDHomerun on 192.168.9.88 to DVR from it

That requirement means it has to remain a bridge (i.e. remain in the 'LAN–LAN' connection). Bridges connect their ports into a single physical subnet, while routers separate them into different subnets. So if the SmartHome is actually in "router mode", *that* will isolate its network, and trying to use the same network number won't undo that – you'll just end up with two identically numbered networks.

The main problem is that DHCP discovery works a lot like IoT discovery. If you have a single subnet bridged across both MainHome and SmartHome, then devices on one will be able to send out a broadcast search query for devices on the other, and discover media servers and IoT devices across the two SSIDs – but they'll *also* be able to discover DHCP servers the same way.

If you have two DHCP servers ("like if you used a Raspberry Pi as a DHCP server"), all devices will simply get offers from *both* servers, and the only thing separating them is that the "local" one will be a tiny bit faster. Most of the time. This might seem to work a lot of the time, but there'll be many cases where it won't work as intended, and a device on SSID A will just end up talking to the DHCP server meant for SSID B – they're both on the same subnet after all.

> The 2 routers are connected via LAN ports, not using the WAN port of either. So it's simply 2 DHCP servers, like if you used a Raspberry Pi as a DHCP server

> if it will cause problems I can have all the DHCP handled through the main router, but I prefer the sorting for my personal organization

You can still achieve organization with just a single DHCP server. A lot of DHCP servers support *statically configured leases,* where a given MAC address (or a given DHCP Client-ID) is manually assigned an address and will always get a lease for only that address. It's a very common feature that's found in home routers as well.

If your primary router doesn't support this, then you can turn off DHCP on the router, and *use a Raspberry Pi* as the only DHCP server. Just make sure the Pi advertises the correct "default gateway" parameter (pointing at the real router, not at the Pi itself).

(We do this at work: each entire building has one giant 10.X.0.0/16 subnet, but PCs in room 34 are assigned static leases 10.X.34.y, PCs in room 71 are assigned static leases 10.X.71.y, and so on.)

(It's also sometimes possible to have a DHCP server *ignore* certain devices and only answer to others, and have another DHCP server do the opposite (e.g. make server 1 only send offers to PCs and ignore IoT devices by their MAC address). That way, two DHCP servers could coexist. But, if both of your DHCP servers are capable of this... more likely than not they're also capable of issuing "static leases" to devices, which again lets you achieve the same thing with just one server.)

Comment: I guess it was worded somewhat confusingly.

Comment: The Split-DHCP is more to help me keep the 2 groups separate. My initial setup had the SmartHome router setup as a dumb bridge. Essentially keeping the SmartHome devices on a separate SSID. THAT is what is supposed to be reducing congestion of the WiFi "lanes" the Split-DHCP is just so the SmartHome devices stay in an IP range together

Comment: It's no longer a bridge, or rather once I implement it it will not be, but I NEED them to be on the same Subnet. **Google Home Mini 1** on 192.168.9.56 needs to be able to see **MediaServer** on 192.168.9.106 to play the music stored there without sending it out & back onto the network, likewise **MediaServer** on 106 needs to see **HDHomerun** on 192.168.9.88 to DVR from it

Comment: Well, if it's no longer a bridge, that literally means it will **"physically"** no longer be on the same subnet – a router separates subnets just by being a router. After that, trying to use the same subnet _numbering_ on both subnets will not change the fact that they're still two separate subnets.

Comment: My congestion separation is from the different routers, the Split-DHCP simply keeps the IPs grouped, if it will cause problems I can have all the DHCP handled through the main router, but I prefer the sorting for my personal organization

Comment: The 2 routers are connected via LAN ports, not using the WAN port of either. So it's simply 2 DHCP servers, like if you used a Raspberry Pi as a DHCP server

Comment: Right, but having SmartHome as a bridge already gave you the same "congestion separation", as you mention. (To clarify, when I said "a router" that implied it actually being in router mode and not in bridge mode.) So the problem is: if the SmartHome is being used as a bridge (LAN-to-LAN), then you have a single subnet where devices can discover each other – _but_ that also means they can see _all_ of the DHCP servers, and potentially choose the wrong one at random. And if the SmartHome is being used as a router (WAN port), then DHCP discovery is isolated, but IoT discovery is isolated as well.

Comment: Right. Which is an issue I considered, & if it happens, it happens, not the end of the world, but since the "SmartHome" DHCP sits between the device & the other it SHOULD receive its DHCPs from the one it encounters 1st. From everything I know, outdated as it may be, & can find it should work & the possibility of the DHCPs coming from the "wrong" server, should only effect my organization & not cause any problems. I know there's a slight latency increase on the 2nd router because of how it's connected, but I'm okay with that for the SmartHome devices

Comment: As a possible benefit, if a device looses internet access because of a DHCP problem & it instead finds the other DHCP server so much the better

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the thing you said about making the DHCP assign a statically configured lease range to the AP. I cannot find any information about it. I'm considering adding back my old Asus AC68U to use solely as the DHCP & Network management because I don't like the UI of the new one. It has Asus Merlin firmware on it, but I can only find unique static reservations, can you give me a little more information about it, or a link to find more information?

Comment: You can't assign a range to the whole AP, as it's practically invisible to the DHCP server; it can't distinguish clients on different APs on the same subnet – so instead you'd assign individual leases (reservations) to devices. Whenever you connect a new device, it gets a random lease, open the settings page, edit the lease to statically reserve an appropriate IP address, done.

Comment: Ah. Gotcha. I thought you were saying you assigned a range to devices that connected on the router dynamically within a static range. It's something I hadn't seen before but it sounded like it would more reliably give me what I was trying to imperfectly juryrig

Comment: "(We do this at work: each entire building has one giant 10.X.0.0/16 subnet, but PCs in room 34 are assigned static leases 10.X.34.y, PCs in room 71 are assigned static leases 10.X.71.y, and so on.)" so what you're saying is that you manually assign each static lease but choose those in the "34" or "71" house for those that live in those rooms. Makes sense. That's essentially what I have done previously, but I've found some SmartHome stuff doesn't like it, like the Harmony Hubs I believe, they occasionally loose connection with a static lease, change it & it's good for awhile then same prob

Comment: Hmm, they're not supposed to break; maybe your router does the thing where static leases are given out with "infinite" expiry time instead of the usual X-hour renewal? I've seen some routers do that, and I can kind of imagine the lack of renewals causing some mysterious issues... (In our case with Mikrotik RouterOS and previously with pfSense, even though the leases are static, they're still renewed per usual schedule every 2 hours, so there's actually no way for devices distinguish "static" vs non-"static" leases.)

Comment: Well, I've had the same connectivity issue with multiples of the same device, on multiple different routers connected to different home Internet locations (though it is possible they were all from the same service provider, Cox, that I know at least 2 were. I'm pretty sure the Harmony Hub was one that I went through it with, & I have 6 of them, some even different models (older/newer & remote/keyboard differences but still "Harmony Hub"s) connections have been through Linksys, Cox Mesh, Nighthawk, & Belkin routers with different setups, the same issue, so the only common left is DHCP Res

Comment: Well, DHCP Reservations & devices unable to setup Static IPs from the devices. Another was a Smart outlet that I had at least 4 of, ran into the same connectivity loss problem randomly (like it happened sometimes months apart) thus my resistance to DHCP Reservations for SmartHome devices

Comment: The way I see it, some "Smart" Home devices aren't very smart. My best guess is that they perform their reservations in a weird way. Like, maybe instead of saying "Hey DHCP, I need an IP, what should I use?" & then using the one the DHCP says to, they ask "Hey router, I need an IP, what ones are free in the area you serve?" & decides to choose one in that range itself. Some evidence of this is that they rarely get the next available one like most things do

Comment: So just ran into the issue so thought I'd outline it a bit more, Vizio TVs seem to not exactly do their DHCP request correctly. They seem to be ignoring the IP reservation 1 in 10 times or so & sometimes will take a different IP, even one that is already in use. I dislike their Smart TVs in general, but I have to deal with 3 of them & they all seem to do this, but they always pull their self-chosen IP from the range I have set. If those problems occur with it overlapping say a Google Home, the google home seems to work fine anyway, & the switches too. But not when it overlaps a computer

Comment: The problem is that the IP address cannot be "self-chosen", as DHCP clients **don't actually know** where the configured range begins or ends – it's the DHCP server that picks a single address and offers it. (While clients can re-request a specific address that they got earlier, they still do so completely blind, not even knowing if it's appropriate for the current subnet at all – so even in that case they have to pay attention to the server's ACK/NAK.)

Comment: I'm not sure why or how it happens, I only know it's an annoyance I have run into multiple times, from Vizio TVs. I personally loathe them at this point, but there are 3 in my house for other people who live with me, so I just have to deal with them. From the information I have it SEEMS as though they will stay in the range, but they sometimes will overlap another device. They also have general connectivity issues & when I've tried manual IPs set up on the TVs they will sometimes have no internet until they are unplugged & plugged back in. That's why I wanted them to be on a separate DHCP, lol